# Использовать новую переменную в WHERE

Tags: mysql

Как использовать новую переменную в WHERE? Пишет `Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT id, 
       rat, 
       (SELECT Count(`id`) AS `cnt` 
        FROM   table2 
        WHERE  sid = table1.id 
               AND `date2` > 'date3') AS `c` 
FROM   table1 `table1` 
WHERE  `rat` > `c`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table1.id, table1.rat, 
    (SELECT COUNT (table2.id) FROM table2 WHERE table2.sid=table.id) as c 
    FROM table1
) as temp
WHERE temp.rat > temp.c
```